# How to use getServerSideProps for every pages in next.js?

Tags: cookies, next.js

I have set a cookie with nookies which store the values of all the products selected by user.
I want to fetch the cookie in server side using getServerSideProps and pass the value as props. I have to display the value of cookie on all pages.

When I tried getServerSideProps in _app.js. It did not worked and it did not even run the code.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I too need user data on all pages, it seems so simple but it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no, I haven't solved it yet. Seems like the only way to do it is on client side.

Answer (score 39):

As of now, there isn't a built-in way to do it, so I've resorted to doing the following.

First, I created a file that holds the `getServerSideProps` function I want to run on every page:

```js
// lib/serverProps.js
export default async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  // do something
  return {
    // data
  };
}
```

Then in every page (yes, *every*, I can't find a workaround; it might even be helpful if you don't need the code to execute on server pages), do:

```js
import getServerSideProps from "../lib/serverProps";

// other stuff...

export { getServerSideProps };
```

or

```js
// other stuff...

export { default as getServerSideProps } from "../lib/serverProps";
```

---

If you want to add other code to run inside `getServerSideProps` for a specific page, you could do something along the lines...

```js
import serverProps from "../lib/serverProps";

// other stuff...

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  // do custom page stuff...
  return {
    ...await serverProps(ctx),
    ...{
      // pretend this is what you put inside
      // the return block regularly, e.g.
      props: { junk: 347 }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: This method helps me to integrate **protected** and **auth** route from server side, very easily. Thank you. Marking this as useful.

Comment: what if the page has its own `getServerSideProps` it wanna run alongside with this common `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: @sumit see the last code block

Answer (score 24):

`getServerSideProps` does not work in `_app.js`. see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats).

you could use the older `getInitialProps` in your custom app component but then the automatic static optimisation is disabled, which is something Next.js bets on heavily.

it might be worth digging into your cookie use case and figure out if you really need to read it on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Although having some user data available on all pages seems pretty common, how would you solve this issue in nextjs? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any resolution around this? I desperately need it.

Answer (score 4):

For those wanting to share state received from a page's `getServerSideProps` function to global components in `pages/_app.tsx`, I've pieced this solution together.

- Create a shared `getServerSideProps` function to include on all pages
- Create a shared `useSetUserStorage` custom hook to include on all pages
- Listen for `localStorage` changes with custom event listener in global component (e.g. `GlobalNav`)

It's a work around, but is working for me so far (note that it includes some specifics to my use of `getServerSideProps` function).

It's a fair amount of code but hopefully this helps someone:

```js
// src/pages/_app.tsx

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

import GlobalNav from "../components/GlobalNav";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalNav /> // <— your global component
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

```js
// src/utils/getServerSideProps.ts

import { ppinit, ppsession, sess } from "../authMiddleware";
import nc from "next-connect";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { User } from "../types/types";

interface ExtendedReq extends NextApiRequest {
  user: User;
}

interface ServerProps {
  req: ExtendedReq;
  res: NextApiResponse;
}

interface ServerPropsReturn {
  user?: User;
}

//
// Here we use middleware to augment the `req` with the user from passport.js
// to pass to the page
// src: https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/tree/21c9c73fe3746e66033fd51e2aa01d479e267ad6#runreq-res
//
const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }: ServerProps) => {
  // ADD YOUR CUSTOM `getServerSideProps` code here
  const middleware = nc()
    .use(sess, ppinit, ppsession)
    .get((req: Express.Request, res: NextApiResponse, next) => {
      next();
    });

  try {
    await middleware.run(req, res);
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error
  }

  const props: ServerPropsReturn = {};
  if (req.user) props.user = req.user;
  return { props };
};

export interface Props {
  user?: User;
}

export default getServerSideProps;
```

```js
// src/hooks.ts

import { useEffect } from "react";

import { User } from "./types/types";

export const useSetUserStorage = (user?: User) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
    }

    // whether setting or removing the user, dispatch event so that `GlobalNav`
    // component (which is above the page implementing this hook in the
    // component hierarchy) can be updated to display the user status.  we
    // can't use `window.addEventListener('storage', handler)` as this only
    // works for listening for events from other pages
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event("localStorageUserUpdated"));
  });

  return null;
};
```

```js
// src/pages/index.tsx (or any page)

import { useSetUserStorage } from "../hooks";

import { Props } from "../utils/getServerSideProps";
export { default as getServerSideProps } from "../utils/getServerSideProps";

export default function Home({ user }: Props) {
  useSetUserStorage(user);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to my app {user?.username}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
// src/components/GlobalNav.ts (or another global component)

import { useEffect, useState, MouseEvent } from "react";

import { User } from "../types/types";

const GlobalNav = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserLocalStorage = () => {
      const userString = localStorage.getItem("user");

      try {
        if (userString) {
          setUser(JSON.parse(userString));
        } else {
          setUser(null);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // handle parse error
      }
    };

    handleUserLocalStorage();
    // this component (`GlobalNav`) lives at the application level, above the
    // pages, but the pages receive the user object from `getServerSideProps`,
    // so this listener listens for when a page tells us the user object has
    // changed so we can update the `user` state here.
    document.addEventListener(
      "localStorageUserUpdated",
      handleUserLocalStorage,
      false,
    );

    return () => {
      // remove listener if component unmounts
      document.removeEventListener(
        "localStorageUserUpdated",
        handleUserLocalStorage,
      );
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {user?.username}
    </div>
  );
};
export default GlobalNav;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) for every page in your Next.js application, you'll need to define it in each page component file. However, if you're looking to share common logic across multiple pages, you can use a higher-order function.

If you have common logic that you want to run on the server side for multiple pages, you can create a higher-order function to wrap the getServerSideProps function.

```js
// utils/sharedServerSideLogic.js
export const sharedServerSideLogic = (getServerSidePropsFunc) => {
  return async (context) => {
    // Common server-side logic here

    if (getServerSidePropsFunc) {
      return getServerSidePropsFunc(context);
    }

    return { props: {} };
  };
};
```

Then, in your page component files, you can use this higher-order function:

```js
// pages/index.js
import { sharedServerSideLogic } from '../utils/sharedServerSideLogic';

function HomePage(props) {
  return <div>Welcome to the Home Page</div>;
}

export const getServerSideProps = sharedServerSideLogic(async (context) => {
  // Page-specific server-side logic here
  return {
    props: {},
  };
});

export default HomePage;
```

Repeat the above steps for every page where you want to use getServerSideProps.

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different technique. Every page, in my case, has its own `getServerSideProps` and I was looking for a more functional approach. Also I'm using GraphQL, but the idea is the same no matter which data fetching API you choose. A regular `getServerSideProps` would look like this -

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {

    const { slug } = context.query

    const { data: profile } = await client.query({ query: GetProfileDocument, variables: { slug } })

    return {
        props: {
            ...(await getSelf(context)),
            profile: profile?.GetProfile[0],
        },
    }
}
```

In the `props` you can see the `await` statement, which is called in all pages. And in the few cases I don't need it, it's gone. This is what `getSelf` looks like -

```js
const getSelf = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => {
    const session = await getSession(context)

    let self = null

    if (session) {
        const { data } = await client.query({
            query: GetProfileDocument,
            variables: { secret: session?.secretSauce as string },
        })

        self = data.GetProfile[0]
    }

    return { self, sessionData: session }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something server action(like `router.use("*", handler)` in express) for every page, not run literally `getServerSideProps`, do following.

```
// pages/api/cookie.js

export default function setLocalehandler(req, res) {
  // do some server action
  return res.json(data); //cookie data
}
```

```
// context/CookieContext.js

const LocaleContext = createContext();

const LocaleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/cookie").then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [router.pathname]);
  return <LocaleContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</LocaleContext.Provider>;
};

export { LocaleProvider, LocaleContext };
```

```
// pages/_app.js

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <LocaleProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </LocaleProvider>
  );
}
```

so now, If you want to use cookie data in page

```
// pages/foo/bar.js
export default function Page() {
  const cookie = useContext(CookieContext);
}
```