# TypeError: getCurves is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to give custom claims to certain users for my react web app and I couldn't get past this error.

Error:

```
TypeError: getCurves is not a function
./node_modules/jose/lib/registry/ec_curves.js
  2 | 
  3 | const curves = new Set()
  4 | 
> 5 | if (getCurves().includes('prime256v1')) {
  6 |   curves.add('P-256')
  7 | }
  8 |
```

and this is the function the function which triggers it

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {
  admin: true,
})
```

this is how my admin sdk looks like

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

import serviceAccount from './Servicekey.json';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: <databaseURL>
});

export default admin;
```

I used to update user profile (password, email) in similar fashion from my system but cannot do that either.

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from Firebase Admin ?

Comment: i never got such error with my web app before ... it is after using firebase-admin that i am facing this error.

Comment: Web app? Where are you using `firebase-admin`? You *must not* use it on frontend. That has admin privileges, doesn't obey security rules and has full access to your Firebase project. You should use that in secure env like server or cloud functions only. It's not supposed to be used in frontend.

Comment: yeah ... i am just testing or basically giving just a single admin token to a user. i have no intentions of publishing it to all user base.

Comment: I'd recommend using a node project and not react to do s or you can try Firebase Functions emulator locally.

Comment: i would take that recommendation for sure, thankyou but i do not understand what is casing this bug when it was working just fine. Also i used a different project which shares the same firebase setup and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used getToken() from next-auth

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a couple of months, but I just spent several days figuring this out, I ended up reverting to an older version of firebase-admin.
Try reverting to version 9.0.0.

I reverted by going to the package.json file and changing the firebase-admin version to 9.0.0 then running "npm i".

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error from `firebase-admin` v11.5 which was running in a NextJS v12 `getServerSideProps` function. The server was not erroring, but the client was which wasn't making any sense.

It turned out that I was running the `firebase-admin` `verifyIdToken` in my `_app.tsx` file in this function

```
MyApp.getServerSideProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => { ... }
```

is attached to the page component, and isn't server-side only at all, instead of this

```
export async function getServerSideProps(appContext: AppContext) { ... }
```

NOTE: after posting this I discovered that [getServerSideProps will not run at all in `_app.tsx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65670813/2036135), but I swear it was doing it that night, and next morning, it was not.